# In an IIS Log what does "..." mean in a "cs(Cookie)" column?

Tags: log-files, iis, cookie

I've checked MSDN, and the W3C format, but nothing seems to explain what causes IIS to output "..." in the "cs(Cookie)" column.

My assumption is that the cookie is "too big", but I'd like to know for sure and also what is the limit before IIS outputs "..."?

Answer (score 2):

You are correct. If the log field exceeds the default limit size it would show "...".

Comment: Any idea on whatthe default limit size is? Or if there's a way to change it?

Comment: The default size is 4KB and there is no registry setting or Metabase key to change this.

Comment: MS KB that documents this limit: https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/2809913